# Wordpress languages update

Tags: wordpress, po, mo

I need to disable automatic language update in Wordpress. After a search on Google I've added these 2 lines in my wp-config.php:

```
define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

but WordPress continues to update .po and .mo files.

How can I disable automatic update? Why these lines of code don't work?

Answer (score 0):

This disables all translation updates:

add_filter( 'auto_update_translation', '__return_false' );

Read more info here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates#Configuration_via_Filters

Comment: Is correct to add this line of code at the beginning of functions.php of my theme?